# How to display multi line in Label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

The following is the record which I am getting from the database:

"Dear:Thank you for applying to school. We have received your application to the program.As of today,we have received the following for your application:"

I am trying to put the above value into a label. My label looks like the following:

```
<div id="secondd" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2;">
       <asp:Label id="valueIntroduction" Cssclass="labelarea" runat="server">   </asp:Label>
       <div  class="line"></div>
```

My problem is value is not getting fitted into the label. How to make it as a multi line label?

Here is the HTML that contains this div:

```
<div id="first" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2"> 
    <div id="second" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2"> 
        <div id="Introduction" style="float:left;width:100%" class="wote">     
            Introduction: 
        </div> 
        <div class="line"></div> 
    </div>   
    <div id="secondd" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2;"> 
        <asp:Literal id="valueIntroduction" runat="server"> </asp:Literal> 
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Sure I will keep this in mind. I am new to stack overflow. I edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the text to wrap based on the in-line style of your outer `<div>`, you can change the `<asp:label>` to an `<asp:literal>` and use CSS to style the outer `<div>`.

The difference is that a Literal does not render any HTML markup, whereas a Label will be wrapped in a  element. The Literal just inserts the exact text you have, letting your existing HTML and CSS do the styling.

An example of a different style would be:

Less percentage, note 20% instead of 50% for the `width` attribute:

```
<div id="secondd" style="float:left;width:20%;background-color:#C0D5F2;">
```

Or, use a dedicated value of pixels (denoted by the `px`)

```
<div id="secondd" style="float:left;width:150px;background-color:#C0D5F2;">
```

You can even indent the text, using `text-indent`. I suggest to google some basic CSS and just try different things out, it is the best way to learn.

You just have to play with it to see how it fits in your webpage. Once you get the hang of it, note for future reference that you can use style sheets for this stuff which will make your code cleaner and allow you to create reusable, easily editable styles for your application.

Comment: Do you know CSS? You have some in-line CSS on your example. I don't know the rest of your page, so it's hard to say, but you need to set the width of the <div> using the width CSS property (which you already have) to be smaller so that the text wraps. Since I don't see your HTML, the 50% value you have in there now means nothing as I don't know what it is 50% of...

Comment: <div id="first" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2">
        <div id="second" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2">
        <div id="Introduction" style="float:left;width:100%" class="wote">  
            Introduction: </div>
    <div  class="line"></div>
    </div> 
    
       <div id="secondd" style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:#C0D5F2;">
       <div
       <asp:Literal id="valueIntroduction" runat="server">   </asp:Literal>
       <div  class="line"></div>